# Non blocking wait while reading data from serial in VB

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port, delay, sleep

I have a procedural GUI method that needs to retrieve data from serial several times.

Each time it does so, it needs to wait for serial data function to finish (e.g., that function works for 15 seconds by averaging all the data received from the serial).

What is some non blocking ways of waiting on this?
At first I tried `Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000)`, however this locks up the program completely.

I also tried very similar method (that still uses sleep but at smaller intervals). Blocking is still there, just at 0.5 seconds interval.

```
Public Sub ResponsiveSleep(ByRef iMilliSeconds As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, iHalfSeconds As Integer = iMilliSeconds / 500
    For i = 1 To iHalfSeconds
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500) : Application.DoEvents()
    Next i
End Sub
```

Should I make serial read function a separate thread before I call wait function?

Comment: Threads are bad practise nowadays, perhaps you could look into async functions and `Tasks`

Comment: But yes, you should always keep your working and your GUI seperate if possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking I/O and any other blocking calls should be put on a separate thread. You might end up with something like:

```
Public Async Sub MyUserInterfaceEventThatMakesTheAsyncCallWork()
    Dim result as String = Await ResponsiveSleep()
    MyUserInterface.Text = result
End Sub

Public Async Function ResponsiveSleep() As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(10000) 'however long you want the delay to be, or delay logic here
    'Calls here should always be Await, or they'll be synchronous
    Return "the result of my thing!"
End Function
```

This is useful because you don't have to think too hard about it. As long as you're asynchronous in the other function, you can write it more or less as if it was synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

If data are received without polling, you might implement a DataReceived event.
More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am actually using DataReceived event. However, how do I let it run without Thread.Sleep locking it up (even in my ResponsiveSleep function).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The event is fired whenever  the internal input buffer is greater than ReceivedBytesThreshold Property. The default is 1.
Set it to the number of bytes expected, and then process them.