# Need to add in a delay in the for loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, delay

So i need to add a delay in my for loop as it is happening too past id like the delay to be about 1 second

I have tried Threading.Thread.Sleep() but just delays the whole form from opening

```
        For Movement As Integer = 1 To 100
            Invader.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            Invader.Width = 53
            Invader.Height = 42
            Invader.Top = 50
            Invader.Left = 50
            Invader.ImageLocation = "D:\.Visual Studio\SSD game\Resources\Invader.png"
            Me.Controls.Add(Invader)
            Invader.Location = New Point(12, 12)
        Next
        Timer1.Enabled = True
```

Comment: Make the method [`Async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/async) and then use `Await Task.Delay(1000)` for a one second delay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non blocking wait while reading data from serial in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572607/non-blocking-wait-while-reading-data-from-serial-in-vb)

Comment: Initializing the exact same PictureBox object a hundred times is not useful.  If you want to model a hundred invaders then you need a List(Of Invader).  And a "game loop" to update their actions, you can get a cheap one from that Timer1 you already use.  Set its Interval to 15 or 31.  Also the easiest way to avoid falling into the PictureBox trap, Graphics.DrawImage() is the best way.  Google "windows forms game loop" to find good background info.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchrounously called a delay function from inside your Loop which should be in a method. See below code:

```
Public Async Sub YourLoopThatWorksAsync()
        For Movement As Integer = 1 To 100
            Invader.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            Invader.Width = 53
            Invader.Height = 42
            Invader.Top = 50
            Invader.Left = 50
            Invader.ImageLocation = "D:\.Visual Studio\SSD game\Resources\Invader.png"
            Me.Controls.Add(Invader)
            Invader.Location = New Point(12, 12)

            Dim result as integer = Await ResponsiveSleep()
        Next

End Sub

Public Async Function ResponsiveSleep() As Task(Of Integer)
    Await Task.Delay(1000)  ' 1000ms = 1 sec
    return 1
End Function
```